# Couldn't find index page for 'glue'

Tags: python, python-2.7, easy-install, python-glue

After `easy_install glue` I get:

```
Searching for glue
Reading http://pypi.python.org/simple/glue/
Couldn't find index page for 'glue' (maybe misspelled?)
Scanning index of all packages (this may take a while)
Reading http://pypi.python.org/simple/
No local packages or download links found for glue
Best match: None
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Python27\Scripts\easy_install-script.py", line 8, in <module>
    load_entry_point('setuptools==0.6c11', 'console_scripts', 'easy_install')()
  File "c:\python27\lib\site-packages\setuptools\command\easy_install.py", line 1712, in main
    with_ei_usage(lambda:
  File "c:\python27\lib\site-packages\setuptools\command\easy_install.py", line 1700, in with_ei_usage
    return f()
  File "c:\python27\lib\site-packages\setuptools\command\easy_install.py", line 1716, in <lambda>
    distclass=DistributionWithoutHelpCommands, **kw
  File "C:\Python27\lib\distutils\core.py", line 151, in setup
    dist.run_commands()
  File "C:\Python27\lib\distutils\dist.py", line 953, in run_commands
    self.run_command(cmd)
  File "C:\Python27\lib\distutils\dist.py", line 972, in run_command
    cmd_obj.run()
  File "c:\python27\lib\site-packages\setuptools\command\easy_install.py", line 211, in run
    self.easy_install(spec, not self.no_deps)
  File "c:\python27\lib\site-packages\setuptools\command\easy_install.py", line 434, in easy_install
    self.local_index
  File "c:\python27\lib\site-packages\setuptools\package_index.py", line 475, in fetch_distribution
    return dist.clone(location=self.download(dist.location, tmpdir))
AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'clone'
```

What is the problem ?

Comment: Looks like it's specific to windows. I'm able to install it on osx. Are you using virtualenv? that can help to isolate the problem.

Comment: No. I am not using virtualenv. Sorry for the late reply. And yes, I am on Windows 10.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This issue got fixed after I updated my Python from version 2.7.13 to 2.7.15